# Delete line in Vuetify data-table with delete button in dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have data-table with an edit and delete icon to each line. When using the code below and pressing the delete icon I get a system pop-up and the the line deletes the way I want it. So perfect.

```
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
           <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
           <v-icon small text @click="deleteItem(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </template>
```

Methods script:

```
deleteItem(item) {
   const index = this.companies.indexOf(item);
   confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
   this.companies.splice(index, 1);
},
```

Now instead of the system pop-up I want to have a nice dialog. Like in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYzZPZ?editors=1010.

So I've made this code:

```
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
      <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      <v-icon small @click="dialog2 = true">mdi-delete</v-icon>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog2" max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>Verwijderen</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>Weet je zeker dat je {{item.name}} wenst te verwijderen?</v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog2 = false">Close</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem(item)">Verwijderen</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
```

And with Methods script:

```
    deleteItem(item) {
  const index = this.companies.indexOf(item);
  this.companies.splice(index, 1);
  this.dialog2 = false;
  console.log("Delete success");
},
```

I've added the console log to see if the button actually did something.
When I press the delete icon now I do get the dialoge. When I press "close" everything is fine.
When I press delete I get the message "Delete success" in console but the line is not deleting.
When I press the delete button again the page crashes....Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, positive. It's the same as in CRUD Action on https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are **multiple instances of `v-dialog`** bound to `dialog2` because it's inside a slot that repeats. This is different than the single instance of `window.confirm` that works. So, when you attempt to `deleteItem(item)` the item to delete is always the last in the array.

Put the `v-dialog` dialog outside the `v-data-table`, and keep track of the `itemToDelete` (this same way edit works). Use a method to toggle the dialog and remember the item...

```
showDeleteDialog(item) {
    this.itemToDelete = item
    this.dialogDelete = !this.dialogDelete
},
deleteItem() {
    console.log('deleteItem', this.itemToDelete)
    const index = this.items.indexOf(this.itemToDelete)    
    this.items.splice(index, 1)
    this.dialogDelete = false
},
```

Then the template is...

```
   <v-data-table>
          <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                    <div class="text-truncate">
                      <v-icon
                        small
                        class="mr-2"
                        @click="editItem(item)"
                      >
                        mdi-pencil
                      </v-icon>
                      <v-icon
                        small
                        @click="showDeleteDialog(item)"
                      >
                        mdi-delete
                      </v-icon>
                  </div>
          </template>
   </v-data-table>  

   <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-title>Delete</v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>Weet je zeker dat je `{{itemToDelete.Name}}` wenst te verwijderen?</v-card-text>
                  <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialogDelete = false">Close</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem()">Delete</v-btn>
                  </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/m0nip2TdUv)

Comment: Whaw, what an excellent answer....but I do get an error.  [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: Not sure.. are you using `this.companies`?

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake. Forgot to use companies instead of items...sorry, long day :-).
Thank you very very much for your help